# Outlook 2007 script error

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, script, microsoft-office-2007

I'm trying to set a folder homepage on Outlook 2007. The page works fine on this PC, but when I try it on another machine (specifically a Citrix session), I get a script error.

Whatever I choose the page won't display. Both the PC and the Citrix farm have Outlook 2007. I'm pretty certain it's an Outlook thing, just can't find a fix.

Comment: Might be better off on Stack Overflow. But don't do anything, as if others agree it'll get migrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914202

Cheers